# What happens if a ninja attempts to use the Sharingan Eye to copy a jutsu that is too strong?

Tags: naruto

Naruto's "Bridge Builder" arc implies heavily that stronger chakra is required for stronger jutsu. It is also clear that stronger jutsu require "more energy" from their user, since Zabuza was unable to create strong water clones while Kakashi was in the water prison (and the dialog mentions something to that effect). So, what would happen if someone uses the Sharingan Eye but the jutsu requires stronger chakra than they have to give?

Comment: We already have an answer to that, although in roundabout way. Taijutsu is still jutsu. Rock Lee vs Sasuke fight shows that you can have the fastest, "perfect" Sharingan Eye and perceive everything that is happening but be unable to copy it. It took a lot of training for Sasuke to be able to be close to copying Rock Lee's technique. So, I guess the answer is: that someone will fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sharingan seems to allow the user to deconstruct *how* a jutsu works by

1. Seeing the chakra flow
2. Observing the verbal or physical queues via enhanced visual perception

We know from canon that there are limits to how much copying can be done

1. Kekkai genkai (innate jutsu that are usually inherited traits). We see that from Kakashi during the Bridge Builder arc
2. [Nature transformations](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Nature_transformation). Most ninja have at most two natures (a dominant and secondary, such as Sasuke Uchiha being able to use fire and lightning early on, and later all five release types). A Sharingan user needs to be able to wield the natural element of a given jutsu to properly copy it. The Sharingan simply makes learning other release types easier.

Knowing this, we can surmise that a jutsu requiring more chakra than a user possesses would probably fail, likely in the same way as we see young ninja fail in infusing enough chakra to execute some advanced jutsu. We never see young Sasuke (or later Sarada) executing advanced jutsu at an early age, despite having the ability to copy techniques.